# How to assigne a variable in windows shell?

Tags: windows-7, bash

In the Windows7 shell I have the following working code to print out the current IP adress:

```
@echo off
:: get ipv4
ipconfig | findstr IPv4 | findstr 172 > ipadd.txt

:: For statement to find the numbers
for /F "tokens=13" %%i in (ipadd.txt) do ( 
  echo %%i 
)
del ipadd.txt /Q
```

However, I do not want the IP adress printed out, but stored in a variable, as in the following (not-working) code snippet:

```
@echo off
:: get ipv4
ipconfig | findstr IPv4 | findstr 172 > ipadd.txt

:: For statement to find the numbers
for /F "tokens=13" %%i in (ipadd.txt) do ( 
  set ip=%%i 
)
del ipadd.txt /Q

echo IP is $ip
```

The expected output is (example)

IP is 123.456.7.8

the actual output is

IP is $ip

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged your question with [bash]. You're *not* writing a script for `bash` or `sh` or anything even remotely like the Bourne shell. Windows batch scripts usually run on the `cmd.exe` shell, a descendant of `COMMAND.COM` from MS-DOS, and have completely different syntax.

In particular, **`%name%`, not `$name`**, is the syntax for variables in Windows and MS-DOS batch scripts.

```
echo IP is %ip%
```

While you're at it:

```
for /F "tokens=13" %%i in ('ipconfig | findstr IPv4 | findstr 172') do (
```